# Problem with inserting from input in database

Tags: php, laravel

I have many to many relationship between UserProfile model and UserTv model. Here are the tables.

user_profiles

```
id    user_id    username
 1       1       AuthUser
```

tv

```
id    name
 1    Action
 2    Drama
 3    Comedy
 4    manually added some genre from input from authenticated user
```

user_tv

```
id    user_id    tv_id
 1      1          2
 1      1          4
```

For example, these first three ids in tv table (Action, Drama, Comedy) are inserted through seeders and this fourth id is inserted manually through input text from form by that user who is authenticated. And there lies the my problem. I want that those values that are manually added through input in form to only be able to see that user that inserted those values, and all other users can't. But also I want all users to remain to see those first three values that are generated through seeder. Currently everything works so that all users can see everything. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

UserProfile.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserProfile extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'username',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function tvs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(UserTv::class, 'user_tv', 'user_id', 'tv_id');
    }
}
```

UserTv.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserTv extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tv';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function userProfiles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(UserProfile::class, 'user_tv', 'tv_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('profile/{profile}', 'UserProfileController@showProfile')->name('profile.show');
Route::patch('profile/update-tv-options', 'TvController@updateTvOptions')->name('profile.update.tv.options');
Route::post('profile/insert-tv-options', 'TvController@insertTvOptions')->name('profile.insert.tv.options');
```

TvController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\UserTv;
use App\UserProfile;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests\InsertTvOptionsRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateTvOptionsRequest;

class TvController extends Controller
{
    public function updateTvOptions(UpdateTvOptionsRequest $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $userProfile = UserProfile::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
        $userProfile->update($request->all());

        $data = $request->get('tvsOptions', '[]');
        $userProfile->tvs()->sync($data);

        return redirect()->route('profile.show', [$user->username]);
    }

    public function insertTvOptions(InsertTvOptionsRequest $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $tv = UserTv::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('profile.show', [$user->username]);
    }
}
```

UserProfileController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\UserTv;
use App\UserProfile;

class UserProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function showProfile($username, Request $request)
    {
        $profileId = User::getIdFromUsername($username);
        $userForShowProfile = User::with('userProfile')->where('id', $profileId)->firstOrFail();

        $tvsOptions = UserTv::get();

        $userTvsOptions = UserProfile::findOrFail($profileId)->tvs()->get();

        return view('profile.show', compact('userForShowProfile', 'tvsOptions', 'userTvsOptions'));
    }
}
```

show.blade.php

```
<section data-edit="movies" class="editMovies">
    <h3 class="textBold">Film</h3>
    <form action="{{ route('profile.update.tv.options') }}" method="POST" class="flex">
        @method('PATCH')
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group flex">
            @isset($tvsOptions, $userTvsOptions)
                @foreach($tvsOptions as $option)
                    <div class="interestedIn">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="tvsOptions[]" value="{{ $option->id }}" {{ $userTvsOptions->contains('id', $option->id)? 'checked': ''}}>
                        <label for="">{{ $option->name }}</label>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            @endisset
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="textBold">Button FOR CHECKBOX</label>
            <input type="submit" class="form-control" name="submit" value="BUTTON">
        </div>
    </form>
    <form action="{{ route('profile.insert.tv.options') }}" method="POST" class="flex">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group mt-5">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="INSERT NEW MOVIE GENRE">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="textBold">Button FOR INSERT!!!</label>
            <input type="submit" class="form-control" name="submit" value="BUTTON">
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: any error message?

Comment: No, this works perfectly. But I don't know how to make it so that those values that are inserted through input from form be only visible to that user who inserted it in foreach with checkboxes above.

Comment: you are looping on $tvsOptions , I guess it contains all the datas pulling fron db

Comment: Yes. it contains all data from tv table. And I want to contain first three options for all users and that fourth option for only this user that inserted that. In this example I mean

Comment: you cant recognize here that which tv_id is seeded or inserted !! can u??

Comment: @hitler_jr10 Yeah, actually I can't recognize it.

Comment: Thats why you have to keep a flag for that maybe!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213331/discussion-between-hitler-jr10-and-rose).

Answer (score 1):

> And I want to contain first three options for all users and that fourth option for only this user that inserted that.

Something like this?

```php
$defaultTvsOptions = UserTv::whereIn('name', ['Action', 'Drama', 'Comedy'])->get(); // return only action, drama and comedy. you can use ids.
$userTvsOptions = UserProfile::findOrFail($profileId)->tvs;

$tvsOptions = $defaultTvsOptions->merge($userTvsOptions); // merge default and logged user tvs options
```

To make it more maintainable, you could use `configs` in your root directory of project.

```php
$defaultTvsOptions = UserTv::whereIn('name', config('config name where return the array'));
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I get Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::merge() wjem O ise your first example

Comment: @rose Hi! Im sorry, forget to put the get() mehotd.fixed comment.

Comment: @rose I fix this line `$defaultTvsOptions = UserTv::whereIn('name', ['Action', 'Drama', 'Comedy'])->get();`

Comment: Hey, it works. Just one small thing. Now when I insert in input it writes in database but doesn't show in my checkboxes in foreach and I am the one who inserted it so it should.

Comment: @rose  Could you check `$tvsOptions` usign `dd($tvsOptions)` in the controller? check if the data is correct. `UserProfile::findOrFail($profileId)->tvs` this line getting the tvs data of user.

Comment: @rose Oh, i see. `I am the one who inserted it` in `insertTvOptions()` method after create a UserTv attach to user profile using attach() to relate them.

Comment: Hey I made it to work somehow with your original answer. And one small thing now. When I insert from input it shows checked in checkboxes, but when I uncheck it and submit it insert NULL value in database and also in form. How can I resolve that?

Comment: @rose Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213337/discussion-between-wheesnoza-and-rose).

Answer (score 0):

Hey As you Have a pivot table You can pull the data Like This:

Userprofile model

```
public function tv() {
       return $this->hasManyThrough(
           'Tv class ',
           'user_tv class', 
           'user_id',
           'id',
           'user_id',
           'tv_id'
       );
   }
```

UserController

```
$data = UserProfile::with('tv')
            ->where(condition)        
                ->get();
```